# Final command in script (sed commands) not working

Tags: shell, vim, sed

I have a script file here, called `editfile.script`:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed '{
1i \Game Commence\nAre You Ready???\ 
s/game/Game/g
s/points/Points/g
s/the\sthe/the/g 
/^ *$/d
$a It's time
}' "$1"
```

To edit this file named `GameOverview`

```
This game will begin in 3 minutes.
The objective is to score 10 points.
If you score 10 points, u move to the the next round

Good luck, may the the force b w u
```

Now when I run `.\editfile.script GameOverview` (from the C shell) command line, I receive this output:

```
Game Commence 
Are You Ready???
This Game will begin in 3 minutes.
The objective is to score 10 Points.
If you score 10 points, u move to the next round
Good luck, may the force b w u
```

As you can see, every command has been carried out: *except* for the append command `$a It's time`.  Why has this happened, and how to fix? And I believe it has something to do with the preceding "delete all blank lines" command `/^ *$/d`, for when I got rid of it the "It's time" was appended:

```
Game Commence 
Are You Ready???
This Game will begin in 3 minutes.
The objective is to score 10 Points.
If you score 10 points, u move to the next round

Good luck, may the force b w u
It's time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the single quote in the string you're appending, `It's time`. It ends the opening single quote of your sed command.

You can get a single quote by ending the first quote, putting your single quote between double quotes, then start another single quoted string:

```
$a It'"'"'s time
```

To avoid the problem altogether, you can put your sed commands into a separate file instead of wrapping it in a shell script:

```
$ cat sedscr.sed
1i\
Game Commence\nAre You Ready???
s/game/Game/g
s/points/Points/g
s/the\sthe/the/g
/^ *$/d
$a\
It's time
```

I've also split up the `i` and `a` commands across two lines, which should be the most portable way of issuing these commands.

You can then call it like this:

```
$ sed -f sedscr.sed GameOverview
Game Commence
Are You Ready???
This Game will begin in 3 minutes.
The objective is to score 10 Points.
If you score 10 Points, u move to the next round
Good luck, may the force b w u
It's time
```

Like this, you don't have to treat single quotes special.

Comment: Good catch, but I don't think that's the problem. I changed the appended string to something without a single quote and the problem persisted.

Comment: @KevinMoy Strange, it works for my sed. What about proper syntax for the `a` command, as in `$a \It's time` or even, as mandated by POSIX, ``$a\``, then a newline, then the string to be inserted?

Comment: I think I found the problem. Right below the last line "Good luck, may the force be with you" I found there was an **extra (blank) newline**. Once I removed it from the original, the problem was immediately solved. Do you know why the append wouldn't show due to an extraneous newline at the end?

Comment: Yes :) The `d` command makes your script advance to the next line, because there is nothing left to do, i.e., all the commands following the `d` command are not executed.

Comment: I'm referring to the original text file (to be edited by sed script) when I say extra newline at the end

Comment: @KevinMoy Yes. When sed looks at the last line of your input, it matches the address for the `d` command, so the command gets executed. It will now skip the `$a` command, because that's what `d` does: all commands after it are skipped for the current line. If you swap the `d` and `a` commands, you'll see that it works.